# Possible to include files to be downloaded as part of a Cognito Form

Tags: cognito-forms

I am curious if I can have files in my forms for people to click and download?

And if so, if we could have them show when a certain criteria is met?

Example: Let's say a person chooses what show they want to see (theatre).
They click the show title, and because they clicked "othello" the file for "othello" comes up, and they can download that PDF.

Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

While we do have a File Upload field that users can upload files to your form. We do not offer the ability to upload a file to Cognito, and then add it to your form.

You can upload the file to your own website or another file hosting site, and then provide a link to the file via the Content field. This way your user could click the provided link and view/download the file.